# Remove Annotations from typing.Annotated

Tags: python, regex, annotations, python-sphinx, python-typing

Let's say I have some type aliases, maybe

```py
Point3D = Annotated[tuple[float, float, float], "A 3D Point"]
Points = Annotated[list[Point3D, list[float]], "A collection of points"]
```

If I try to print Points, I get

```py
typing.Annotated[list[typing.Annotated[tuple[float, float, float], 'A 3D Point'] | list[float]], 'A collection of points']
```

I want to only get the `list[tuple[float, float, float]]` part. I tried using `typing.get_args(Points)[0]` but that just gives this:

```py
list[typing.Annotated[tuple[float, float, float], 'A 3D Point'] | list[float]]
```

Where there is still the unwanted `'A 3D Point'`. How can I achieve this? I tried replacing it with the `", '.*?'` regex, but that didn't work, and I'm not experienced enough with regex to be able to figure out why.

Note:
I can't just change all the `Annotated` types to normal type hints because I still need that annotation content to be displayed elsewhere.

Comment: `list[]` expects 1 type argument, not 2. Did you mean to write `list[Point3D | list[float]]` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple: Walk the tree (at runtime) and convert all `Annotated` nodes to their bare-type counterpart. No regex needed.

```py
from typing import Annotated, get_args, get_origin

def convert_annotated_to_bare_types(type_object: type):
  # For a given `X[Y, Z, ...]`:
  # * `get_origin` returns `X`
  # * `get_args` return `(Y, Z, ...)`
  # For non-supported type objects, the return values are
  # `None` and `()` correspondingly.
  origin, args = get_origin(type_object), get_args(type_object)
    
  if origin is None:
    # No origin -> Not a generic/no arguments.
    return type_object
    
  if origin is Annotated:
    # Annotated -> Convert the first argument recursively.
    bare_type = get_args(type_object)[0]
    return convert_annotated_to_bare_types(bare_type)

  # Otherwise, it is a generic. Convert all arguments recursively.
  converted_args = [
    convert_annotated_to_bare_types(arg) for arg in args
  ]
  
  return origin[*converted_args]
```

It works exactly like you would expect, even if `list` is not supposed to take 2 type arguments:

```py
>>> convert_annotated_to_bare_types(Points)
list[tuple[float, float, float], list[float]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Approach by @InSync looks like the most straightforward way, but you can cheat a little to avoid writing this yourself. [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) already strips `Annotated` types by default, so you can leverage it via a temporary function:

```py
def strip_annotations(type_obj: type) -> type:
    def f(x: type_obj): ...  # type: ignore[valid-type]
    return typing.get_type_hints(f)['x']

print(strip_annotations(Points))
# list[tuple[float, float, float], list[float]]
```

It still preserves your incorrect annotation as well.